# How to defer the update at the client side after async postback in updatepanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax, updatepanel

I have an old system which uses `UpdatePanels` of asp.net

After the `postback` is completed, we know that the inside of `UpdatePanel` is updated

Can i delay this update somehow on the client side ? is that possible?

So it will be like, when the `postback` is started, i set a javascript `datetime object` on the client side

Once the `postback` is completed, and the `data` is returned from the server, before updating the `client side interface`, i check how many miliseconds has passed and I **delay** the update of the client side until certain miliseconds has passed

is this possible?

asp.net 4.5 c#

**let me clarify better**

i want each update of the page to be exactly 500 miliseconds after the ajax postback request started

however the server delay is unknown and changes for the every location

let say that for person 1 the server delay is 122 ms

for person 2 the server delay is 234

for person 3 the server delay is 444

so i would be have to delay the page update at the client side

for the person 1 : 378 ms

for the person 2 : 266 ms

for the person 3 : 56 ms

i have checked and i found that there is a function :

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager pageLoading Event
```

### so if i can somehow override the function that this function calls to update the page i can achieve

(*i still dont know what function it calls to complete the update operation on the client side*)

lets assume that inside

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager pageLoading Event
```

`updateTheChanges` function is called

so if i can override this `updateTheChanges` function and call it with a delay i can achieve what i want

I need exactly something like this which will overwrite the update function of the updatepanel. So i can call this function with a delay

[ASP.Net Webforms w/ AJAX Slow Rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359637/asp-net-webforms-w-ajax-slow-rendering)

ty

here the web resource files

1. script resource 1 : http://pastebin.com/0rSCMn3g
2. script resource 2 : http://pastebin.com/GvqwpPv8

script resource 3 below

```
    function WebForm_PostBackOptions(eventTarget, eventArgument, validation, validationGroup, actionUrl, trackFocus, clientSubmit) {
    this.eventTarget = eventTarget;
    this.eventArgument = eventArgument;
    this.validation = validation;
    this.validationGroup = validationGroup;
    this.actionUrl = actionUrl;
    this.trackFocus = trackFocus;
    this.clientSubmit = clientSubmit;
}

function WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(options) {
    var validationResult = true;
    if (options.validation) {
        if (typeof(Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') {
            validationResult = Page_ClientValidate(options.validationGroup);
        }
    }
    if (validationResult) {
        if ((typeof(options.actionUrl) != "undefined") && (options.actionUrl != null) && (options.actionUrl.length > 0)) {
            theForm.action = options.actionUrl;
        }
        if (options.trackFocus) {
            var lastFocus = theForm.elements["__LASTFOCUS"];
            if ((typeof(lastFocus) != "undefined") && (lastFocus != null)) {
                if (typeof(document.activeElement) == "undefined") {
                    lastFocus.value = options.eventTarget;
                } else {
                    var active = document.activeElement;
                    if ((typeof(active) != "undefined") && (active != null)) {
                        if ((typeof(active.id) != "undefined") && (active.id != null) && (active.id.length > 0)) {
                            lastFocus.value = active.id;
                        } else if (typeof(active.name) != "undefined") {
                            lastFocus.value = active.name;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (options.clientSubmit) {
        __doPostBack(options.eventTarget, options.eventArgument);
    }
}
var __pendingCallbacks = new Array();
var __synchronousCallBackIndex = -1;

function WebForm_DoCallback(eventTarget, eventArgument, eventCallback, context, errorCallback, useAsync) {
    var postData = __theFormPostData +
        "__CALLBACKID=" + WebForm_EncodeCallback(eventTarget) +
        "&__CALLBACKPARAM=" + WebForm_EncodeCallback(eventArgument);
    if (theForm["__EVENTVALIDATION"]) {
        postData += "&__EVENTVALIDATION=" + WebForm_EncodeCallback(theForm["__EVENTVALIDATION"].value);
    }
    var xmlRequest, e;
    try {
        xmlRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            xmlRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {}
    }
    var setRequestHeaderMethodExists = true;
    try {
        setRequestHeaderMethodExists = (xmlRequest && xmlRequest.setRequestHeader);
    } catch (e) {}
    var callback = new Object();
    callback.eventCallback = eventCallback;
    callback.context = context;
    callback.errorCallback = errorCallback;
    callback.async = useAsync;
    var callbackIndex = WebForm_FillFirstAvailableSlot(__pendingCallbacks, callback);
    if (!useAsync) {
        if (__synchronousCallBackIndex != -1) {
            __pendingCallbacks[__synchronousCallBackIndex] = null;
        }
        __synchronousCallBackIndex = callbackIndex;
    }
    if (setRequestHeaderMethodExists) {
        xmlRequest.onreadystatechange = WebForm_CallbackComplete;
        callback.xmlRequest = xmlRequest;
        // e.g. http:
        var action = theForm.action || document.location.pathname,
            fragmentIndex = action.indexOf('#');
        if (fragmentIndex !== -1) {
            action = action.substr(0, fragmentIndex);
        }
        if (!__nonMSDOMBrowser) {
            var queryIndex = action.indexOf('?');
            if (queryIndex !== -1) {
                var path = action.substr(0, queryIndex);
                if (path.indexOf("%") === -1) {
                    action = encodeURI(path) + action.substr(queryIndex);
                }
            } else if (action.indexOf("%") === -1) {
                action = encodeURI(action);
            }
        }
        xmlRequest.open("POST", action, true);
        xmlRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
        xmlRequest.send(postData);
        return;
    }
    callback.xmlRequest = new Object();
    var callbackFrameID = "__CALLBACKFRAME" + callbackIndex;
    var xmlRequestFrame = document.frames[callbackFrameID];
    if (!xmlRequestFrame) {
        xmlRequestFrame = document.createElement("IFRAME");
        xmlRequestFrame.width = "1";
        xmlRequestFrame.height = "1";
        xmlRequestFrame.frameBorder = "0";
        xmlRequestFrame.id = callbackFrameID;
        xmlRequestFrame.name = callbackFrameID;
        xmlRequestFrame.style.position = "absolute";
        xmlRequestFrame.style.top = "-100px"
        xmlRequestFrame.style.left = "-100px";
        try {
            if (callBackFrameUrl) {
                xmlRequestFrame.src = callBackFrameUrl;
            }
        } catch (e) {}
        document.body.appendChild(xmlRequestFrame);
    }
    var interval = window.setInterval(function() {
        xmlRequestFrame = document.frames[callbackFrameID];
        if (xmlRequestFrame && xmlRequestFrame.document) {
            window.clearInterval(interval);
            xmlRequestFrame.document.write("");
            xmlRequestFrame.document.close();
            xmlRequestFrame.document.write('<html><body><form method="post"><input type="hidden" name="__CALLBACKLOADSCRIPT" value="t"></form></body></html>');
            xmlRequestFrame.document.close();
            xmlRequestFrame.document.forms[0].action = theForm.action;
            var count = __theFormPostCollection.length;
            var element;
            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                element = __theFormPostCollection[i];
                if (element) {
                    var fieldElement = xmlRequestFrame.document.createElement("INPUT");
                    fieldElement.type = "hidden";
                    fieldElement.name = element.name;
                    fieldElement.value = element.value;
                    xmlRequestFrame.document.forms[0].appendChild(fieldElement);
                }
            }
            var callbackIdFieldElement = xmlRequestFrame.document.createElement("INPUT");
            callbackIdFieldElement.type = "hidden";
            callbackIdFieldElement.name = "__CALLBACKID";
            callbackIdFieldElement.value = eventTarget;
            xmlRequestFrame.document.forms[0].appendChild(callbackIdFieldElement);
            var callbackParamFieldElement = xmlRequestFrame.document.createElement("INPUT");
            callbackParamFieldElement.type = "hidden";
            callbackParamFieldElement.name = "__CALLBACKPARAM";
            callbackParamFieldElement.value = eventArgument;
            xmlRequestFrame.document.forms[0].appendChild(callbackParamFieldElement);
            if (theForm["__EVENTVALIDATION"]) {
                var callbackValidationFieldElement = xmlRequestFrame.document.createElement("INPUT");
                callbackValidationFieldElement.type = "hidden";
                callbackValidationFieldElement.name = "__EVENTVALIDATION";
                callbackValidationFieldElement.value = theForm["__EVENTVALIDATION"].value;
                xmlRequestFrame.document.forms[0].appendChild(callbackValidationFieldElement);
            }
            var callbackIndexFieldElement = xmlRequestFrame.document.createElement("INPUT");
            callbackIndexFieldElement.type = "hidden";
            callbackIndexFieldElement.name = "__CALLBACKINDEX";
            callbackIndexFieldElement.value = callbackIndex;
            xmlRequestFrame.document.forms[0].appendChild(callbackIndexFieldElement);
            xmlRequestFrame.document.forms[0].submit();
        }
    }, 10);
}

function WebForm_CallbackComplete() {
    for (var i = 0; i < __pendingCallbacks.length; i++) {
        callbackObject = __pendingCallbacks[i];
        if (callbackObject && callbackObject.xmlRequest && (callbackObject.xmlRequest.readyState == 4)) {
            if (!__pendingCallbacks[i].async) {
                __synchronousCallBackIndex = -1;
            }
            __pendingCallbacks[i] = null;
            var callbackFrameID = "__CALLBACKFRAME" + i;
            var xmlRequestFrame = document.getElementById(callbackFrameID);
            if (xmlRequestFrame) {
                xmlRequestFrame.parentNode.removeChild(xmlRequestFrame);
            }
            WebForm_ExecuteCallback(callbackObject);
        }
    }
}

function WebForm_ExecuteCallback(callbackObject) {
    var response = callbackObject.xmlRequest.responseText;
    if (response.charAt(0) == "s") {
        if ((typeof(callbackObject.eventCallback) != "undefined") && (callbackObject.eventCallback != null)) {
            callbackObject.eventCallback(response.substring(1), callbackObject.context);
        }
    } else if (response.charAt(0) == "e") {
        if ((typeof(callbackObject.errorCallback) != "undefined") && (callbackObject.errorCallback != null)) {
            callbackObject.errorCallback(response.substring(1), callbackObject.context);
        }
    } else {
        var separatorIndex = response.indexOf("|");
        if (separatorIndex != -1) {
            var validationFieldLength = parseInt(response.substring(0, separatorIndex));
            if (!isNaN(validationFieldLength)) {
                var validationField = response.substring(separatorIndex + 1, separatorIndex + validationFieldLength + 1);
                if (validationField != "") {
                    var validationFieldElement = theForm["__EVENTVALIDATION"];
                    if (!validationFieldElement) {
                        validationFieldElement = document.createElement("INPUT");
                        validationFieldElement.type = "hidden";
                        validationFieldElement.name = "__EVENTVALIDATION";
                        theForm.appendChild(validationFieldElement);
                    }
                    validationFieldElement.value = validationField;
                }
                if ((typeof(callbackObject.eventCallback) != "undefined") && (callbackObject.eventCallback != null)) {
                    callbackObject.eventCallback(response.substring(separatorIndex + validationFieldLength + 1), callbackObject.context);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

function WebForm_FillFirstAvailableSlot(array, element) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (!array[i]) break;
    }
    array[i] = element;
    return i;
}
var __nonMSDOMBrowser = (window.navigator.appName.toLowerCase().indexOf('explorer') == -1);
var __theFormPostData = "";
var __theFormPostCollection = new Array();
var __callbackTextTypes = /^(text|password|hidden|search|tel|url|email|number|range|color|datetime|date|month|week|time|datetime-local)$/i;

function WebForm_InitCallback() {
    var formElements = theForm.elements,
        count = formElements.length,
        element;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        element = formElements[i];
        var tagName = element.tagName.toLowerCase();
        if (tagName == "input") {
            var type = element.type;
            if ((__callbackTextTypes.test(type) || ((type == "checkbox" || type == "radio") && element.checked)) && (element.id != "__EVENTVALIDATION")) {
                WebForm_InitCallbackAddField(element.name, element.value);
            }
        } else if (tagName == "select") {
            var selectCount = element.options.length;
            for (var j = 0; j < selectCount; j++) {
                var selectChild = element.options[j];
                if (selectChild.selected == true) {
                    WebForm_InitCallbackAddField(element.name, element.value);
                }
            }
        } else if (tagName == "textarea") {
            WebForm_InitCallbackAddField(element.name, element.value);
        }
    }
}

function WebForm_InitCallbackAddField(name, value) {
    var nameValue = new Object();
    nameValue.name = name;
    nameValue.value = value;
    __theFormPostCollection[__theFormPostCollection.length] = nameValue;
    __theFormPostData += WebForm_EncodeCallback(name) + "=" + WebForm_EncodeCallback(value) + "&";
}

function WebForm_EncodeCallback(parameter) {
    if (encodeURIComponent) {
        return encodeURIComponent(parameter);
    } else {
        return escape(parameter);
    }
}
var __disabledControlArray = new Array();

function WebForm_ReEnableControls() {
    if (typeof(__enabledControlArray) == 'undefined') {
        return false;
    }
    var disabledIndex = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < __enabledControlArray.length; i++) {
        var c;
        if (__nonMSDOMBrowser) {
            c = document.getElementById(__enabledControlArray[i]);
        } else {
            c = document.all[__enabledControlArray[i]];
        }
        if ((typeof(c) != "undefined") && (c != null) && (c.disabled == true)) {
            c.disabled = false;
            __disabledControlArray[disabledIndex++] = c;
        }
    }
    setTimeout("WebForm_ReDisableControls()", 0);
    return true;
}

function WebForm_ReDisableControls() {
    for (var i = 0; i < __disabledControlArray.length; i++) {
        __disabledControlArray[i].disabled = true;
    }
}

function WebForm_SimulateClick(element, event) {
    var clickEvent;
    if (element) {
        if (element.click) {
            element.click();
        } else {
            clickEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
            clickEvent.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
            if (!element.dispatchEvent(clickEvent)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        event.cancelBubble = true;
        if (event.stopPropagation) {
            event.stopPropagation();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, target) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        var src = event.srcElement || event.target;
        if (src &&
            ((src.tagName.toLowerCase() == "input") &&
                (src.type.toLowerCase() == "submit" || src.type.toLowerCase() == "button")) ||
            ((src.tagName.toLowerCase() == "a") &&
                (src.href != null) && (src.href != "")) ||
            (src.tagName.toLowerCase() == "textarea")) {
            return true;
        }
        var defaultButton;
        if (__nonMSDOMBrowser) {
            defaultButton = document.getElementById(target);
        } else {
            defaultButton = document.all[target];
        }
        if (defaultButton) {
            return WebForm_SimulateClick(defaultButton, event);
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function WebForm_GetScrollX() {
    if (__nonMSDOMBrowser) {
        return window.pageXOffset;
    } else {
        if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollLeft) {
            return document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        } else if (document.body) {
            return document.body.scrollLeft;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

function WebForm_GetScrollY() {
    if (__nonMSDOMBrowser) {
        return window.pageYOffset;
    } else {
        if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) {
            return document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        } else if (document.body) {
            return document.body.scrollTop;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

function WebForm_SaveScrollPositionSubmit() {
    if (__nonMSDOMBrowser) {
        theForm.elements['__SCROLLPOSITIONY'].value = window.pageYOffset;
        theForm.elements['__SCROLLPOSITIONX'].value = window.pageXOffset;
    } else {
        theForm.__SCROLLPOSITIONX.value = WebForm_GetScrollX();
        theForm.__SCROLLPOSITIONY.value = WebForm_GetScrollY();
    }
    if ((typeof(this.oldSubmit) != "undefined") && (this.oldSubmit != null)) {
        return this.oldSubmit();
    }
    return true;
}

function WebForm_SaveScrollPositionOnSubmit() {
    theForm.__SCROLLPOSITIONX.value = WebForm_GetScrollX();
    theForm.__SCROLLPOSITIONY.value = WebForm_GetScrollY();
    if ((typeof(this.oldOnSubmit) != "undefined") && (this.oldOnSubmit != null)) {
        return this.oldOnSubmit();
    }
    return true;
}

function WebForm_RestoreScrollPosition() {
    if (__nonMSDOMBrowser) {
        window.scrollTo(theForm.elements['__SCROLLPOSITIONX'].value, theForm.elements['__SCROLLPOSITIONY'].value);
    } else {
        window.scrollTo(theForm.__SCROLLPOSITIONX.value, theForm.__SCROLLPOSITIONY.value);
    }
    if ((typeof(theForm.oldOnLoad) != "undefined") && (theForm.oldOnLoad != null)) {
        return theForm.oldOnLoad();
    }
    return true;
}

function WebForm_TextBoxKeyHandler(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        var target;
        if (__nonMSDOMBrowser) {
            target = event.target;
        } else {
            target = event.srcElement;
        }
        if ((typeof(target) != "undefined") && (target != null)) {
            if (typeof(target.onchange) != "undefined") {
                target.onchange();
                event.cancelBubble = true;
                if (event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function WebForm_TrimString(value) {
    return value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')
}

function WebForm_AppendToClassName(element, className) {
    var currentClassName = ' ' + WebForm_TrimString(element.className) + ' ';
    className = WebForm_TrimString(className);
    var index = currentClassName.indexOf(' ' + className + ' ');
    if (index === -1) {
        element.className = (element.className === '') ? className : element.className + ' ' + className;
    }
}

function WebForm_RemoveClassName(element, className) {
    var currentClassName = ' ' + WebForm_TrimString(element.className) + ' ';
    className = WebForm_TrimString(className);
    var index = currentClassName.indexOf(' ' + className + ' ');
    if (index >= 0) {
        element.className = WebForm_TrimString(currentClassName.substring(0, index) + ' ' +
            currentClassName.substring(index + className.length + 1, currentClassName.length));
    }
}

function WebForm_GetElementById(elementId) {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        return document.getElementById(elementId);
    } else if (document.all) {
        return document.all[elementId];
    } else return null;
}

function WebForm_GetElementByTagName(element, tagName) {
    var elements = WebForm_GetElementsByTagName(element, tagName);
    if (elements && elements.length > 0) {
        return elements[0];
    } else return null;
}

function WebForm_GetElementsByTagName(element, tagName) {
    if (element && tagName) {
        if (element.getElementsByTagName) {
            return element.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
        }
        if (element.all && element.all.tags) {
            return element.all.tags(tagName);
        }
    }
    return null;
}

function WebForm_GetElementDir(element) {
    if (element) {
        if (element.dir) {
            return element.dir;
        }
        return WebForm_GetElementDir(element.parentNode);
    }
    return "ltr";
}

function WebForm_GetElementPosition(element) {
    var result = new Object();
    result.x = 0;
    result.y = 0;
    result.width = 0;
    result.height = 0;
    if (element.offsetParent) {
        result.x = element.offsetLeft;
        result.y = element.offsetTop;
        var parent = element.offsetParent;
        while (parent) {
            result.x += parent.offsetLeft;
            result.y += parent.offsetTop;
            var parentTagName = parent.tagName.toLowerCase();
            if (parentTagName != "table" &&
                parentTagName != "body" &&
                parentTagName != "html" &&
                parentTagName != "div" &&
                parent.clientTop &&
                parent.clientLeft) {
                result.x += parent.clientLeft;
                result.y += parent.clientTop;
            }
            parent = parent.offsetParent;
        }
    } else if (element.left && element.top) {
        result.x = element.left;
        result.y = element.top;
    } else {
        if (element.x) {
            result.x = element.x;
        }
        if (element.y) {
            result.y = element.y;
        }
    }
    if (element.offsetWidth && element.offsetHeight) {
        result.width = element.offsetWidth;
        result.height = element.offsetHeight;
    } else if (element.style && element.style.pixelWidth && element.style.pixelHeight) {
        result.width = element.style.pixelWidth;
        result.height = element.style.pixelHeight;
    }
    return result;
}

function WebForm_GetParentByTagName(element, tagName) {
    var parent = element.parentNode;
    var upperTagName = tagName.toUpperCase();
    while (parent && (parent.tagName.toUpperCase() != upperTagName)) {
        parent = parent.parentNode ? parent.parentNode : parent.parentElement;
    }
    return parent;
}

function WebForm_SetElementHeight(element, height) {
    if (element && element.style) {
        element.style.height = height + "px";
    }
}

function WebForm_SetElementWidth(element, width) {
    if (element && element.style) {
        element.style.width = width + "px";
    }
}

function WebForm_SetElementX(element, x) {
    if (element && element.style) {
        element.style.left = x + "px";
    }
}

function WebForm_SetElementY(element, y) {
    if (element && element.style) {
        element.style.top = y + "px";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to delay the UpdatePanel refresh without freezing the user interface:

1. In the `pageLoading` event handler, save the ID and the previous HTML of the panels to be updated
2. In the `pageLoad` event handler, save the new HTML of the panels but replace it by the old one
3. After the delay expires, set the new HTML in the updated panels

Here is the client code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var updateTime = 0;
    var updatedPanelArray = [];

    function setUpdateTime() {
        updateTime = new Date(Date.now() + 500);
    }

    function pageLoading(sender, e) {
        updatedPanelArray.length = 0;
        var panels = e.get_panelsUpdating();
        for (var i = 0; i < panels.length; i++) {
            var pnl = panels[i];
            updatedPanelArray.push({ id: pnl.id, oldHTML: pnl.innerHTML });
        }
    }

    function pageLoad(sender, e) {
        if (e.get_isPartialLoad()) {
            for (var i = 0; i < updatedPanelArray.length; i++) {
                var updatedPanel = updatedPanelArray[i];
                var pnl = document.getElementById(updatedPanel.id);
                updatedPanel.newHTML = pnl.innerHTML;
                pnl.innerHTML = updatedPanel.oldHTML;
                setTimeout(refreshUpdatePanel, updateTime - Date.now());
            }
        }
    }

    function refreshUpdatePanel() {
        for (var i = 0; i < updatedPanelArray.length; i++) {
            var updatedPanel = updatedPanelArray[i];
            var pnl = document.getElementById(updatedPanel.id);
            pnl.innerHTML = updatedPanel.newHTML;
        }
    }

    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoading(pageLoading);
</script>
```

The update time is set before triggering the asynchronous postback:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblUpdatePanel1" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnUpdatePanel" runat="server" OnClientClick="setUpdateTime();" OnClick="btnUpdatePanel_Click" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

It can be tested with the following event handler in code-behind (suggestion: set the delay to 5000 ms in the Javascript code to make it obvious):

```
protected void btnUpdatePanel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblUpdatePanel1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

Comment: let me try this looks like the most sense making solution ty

Comment: ah this still breaks the things. the current html has to be not touched until get updated. but this solution updates the current html with old html after the html is updated :( and then it updates it with the new one. so this basically doesnt prevent updatepanel get changed

Comment: Really? I am surprised, because I tested a lot and did not see the new HTML being displayed before restoring the old one.

Comment: i think it can work in many scenarios but it breaks things in my game :(

Comment: hello. i started another bount this time 100 points. i guess it is possible to overwrite somehow : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359637/asp-net-webforms-w-ajax-slow-rendering

Comment: I saw the new bounty. :-)  Just to be sure: the problem with my answer was not that you saw some early refresh or flicker, but rather that you don't want the HTML to change at all (even if the change is not visible on the screen). Is that correct?

Comment: ConnorsFan i found the function which updates the panel after debugging. The function is _scriptIncludesLoadComplete .  the part is   i._updatePanel(o, g.content) . it is at this url : http://pastebin.com/0rSCMn3g . so i need to delay it :D

Comment: ok all we need is overriding _onFormSubmitCompleted function. is it global one?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind the user interface being frozen while waiting, you can delay the refresh by keeping the `pageLoad` event handler busy until the delay expires:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var updateTime = 0;

    function setUpdateTime() {
        updateTime = new Date(Date.now() + 500);
    }

    function pageLoad(sender, e) {
        if (e.get_isPartialLoad()) {
            while (Date.now() < updateTime) { 
                // Loop until the delay expires
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

You can initialize the update time before triggering the asynchronous postback:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        ...
        <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" OnClientClick="setUpdateTime();" ... />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: unfortunately i can not afford freeze

Comment: Yes, I can imagine that. My other solution is much better, IMO.

Comment: are you sure its that your answered?

Comment: @Codeone - Check my other answer.

Comment: i sawed some article in  that answer, i think your a the same person http://cudou.com/pages/dhcdhghf-how-to-defer-the-update-at-the-client-side-after-async-postback-in-updatepanel.html

Comment: http://trello.info/question/view/en/YUhSMGNEb3ZMM04wWVdOcmIzWmxjbVpzYjNjdVkyOXRMM0YxWlhOMGFXOXVjeTh6TnpJek56WTNOUzlvYjNjdGRHOHRaR1ZtWlhJdGRHaGxMWFZ3WkdGMFpTMWhkQzEwYUdVdFkyeHBaVzUwTFhOcFpHVXRZV1owWlhJdFlYTjVibU10Y0c5emRHSmhZMnN0YVc0dGRYQmtZWFJsY0dGdVpXdz0=

Comment: @Codeone - These articles just reproduce the content of this post. The original stuff is here.

Comment: Sir, sorry for my mistake

Comment: @Codeone - No problem. You can test the code however. I would like to know if it works for you (I am still talking about the other answer).

Comment: Im still beginner,  Sir i know your are super user

Answer (score 0):

Use `UpdatePanel.UpdateMode` Property to gets or sets a value that indicates when an UpdatePanel control's content is updated. For more details visit [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.updatemode(v=vs.110).aspx) link.

Comment: ty for answer but not related to my question. it is about when to trigger not when to parse the received response.

Answer (score -1):

You could delay the server side, so all the delays would be more or less equals for everyone.

If this is not an option, you could have a hidden field inside the update panel (or somewhere else). The function that handles the update (in the server side) would calculate the time it took execute, and before finishing, would update this hidden field. Now back in the client side, check the value of this field and calculate the difference between this value and yours 500ms. You could use datetimes or milliseconds.

It's not the prettiest solution but imho, this is not a frequent problem that people want to handle (in fact, I dont think that you should delay a faster response to the slowest one)

Comment: compeltey irrelevant to the question. i guess you didnt even read. if you delay at server side how can you equalize the client side response receive. you can't. because for every call the response time from server changes.

Comment: I guess that the varying time comes from the server side, not from the client. Lets say all users are calling MyServerFunction. For user A, MyServerFunction takes 150ms to execute, for user B, MyServerFunction takes 344ms... 

So just adjust MyServerFunction to elapse your 500ms. Control the time that is used in your server function, and before returning the response from server to the client, wait 500-timeElapsedToExecuteMyServerFunction.

If your varying time comes from the client side, then this is not valid. But most varying times usually comes from server

Comment: No the difference comes from the network delay between different clients. No way to solve it from the server side. You can not expect a client from china and from USA to access a server with the same speeds if the server is located in USA

Comment: Oh, yes, in that case, this solution doesn't work. Maybe you would like to try this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/network-js

You could precalculate the average delay from your current client, calculate your 500ms - your average current delay, and use the settimeout function.

Client A average delay: 150 ms, client B average delay 350ms. Client A makes a call to setTimeOut(yourServerFunction, 500-150ms), client B makes a call to setTimeOut(yourServerFunction, 500-350ms).

This only works with the average delay, but you could get a good aproximation.