# How to add delay to _onFormSubmitCompleted function inside MicrosoftAjaxWebForms

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I am trying to modify MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js file which is default ajax file of asp.net 4.5 and ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit version is 16.1.0.0

Here an example project to test out : https://github.com/FurkanGozukara/tempSite/

Open project and go to trialpage.aspx and click that button. You will see the error

Here the full MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js : http://pastebin.com/pU3rBLKW

It also uses functions from MicrosoftAjax.js if you need that : http://pastebin.com/CPCm9BZy

What I want is, delaying the event `_onFormSubmitCompleted`

I have tried like below but it doesn't work.

```
MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js:914 Uncaught TypeError: this._tempCompleted is not a function
```

It gives the error above

```
    _onFormSubmitCompleted: function (c) {
    console.log("_onFormSubmitCompleted");
    setTimeout(function () {
        this._tempCompleted(c);
    }, 1111);
}, _tempCompleted: function (c) {
    console.log("testcompleted");
    this._processingRequest = true;
    if (c.get_timedOut()) {
        this._endPostBack(this._createPageRequestManagerTimeoutError(), c, null);
        return
    }
    if (c.get_aborted()) {
        this._endPostBack(null, c, null);
        return
    }
    if (!this._request || c.get_webRequest() !== this._request) return;
    if (c.get_statusCode() !== 200) {
        this._endPostBack(this._createPageRequestManagerServerError(c.get_statusCode()), c, null);
        return
    }
    var a = this._parseDelta(c);
    if (!a) return;
    var b, e;
    if (a.asyncPostBackControlIDsNode && a.postBackControlIDsNode && a.updatePanelIDsNode && a.panelsToRefreshNode && a.childUpdatePanelIDsNode) {
        var r = this._updatePanelIDs,
            n = this._updatePanelClientIDs,
            i = a.childUpdatePanelIDsNode.content,
            p = i.length ? i.split(",") : [],
            m = this._splitNodeIntoArray(a.asyncPostBackControlIDsNode),
            o = this._splitNodeIntoArray(a.postBackControlIDsNode),
            q = this._splitNodeIntoArray(a.updatePanelIDsNode),
            g = this._splitNodeIntoArray(a.panelsToRefreshNode),
            h = a.version4;
        for (b = 0, e = g.length; b < e; b += h ? 2 : 1) {
            var j = (h ? g[b + 1] : "") || this._uniqueIDToClientID(g[b]);
            if (!document.getElementById(j)) {
                this._endPostBack(Error.invalidOperation(String.format(Sys.WebForms.Res.PRM_MissingPanel, j)), c, a);
                return
            }
        }
        var f = this._processUpdatePanelArrays(q, m, o, h);
        f.oldUpdatePanelIDs = r;
        f.oldUpdatePanelClientIDs = n;
        f.childUpdatePanelIDs = p;
        f.panelsToRefreshIDs = g;
        a.updatePanelData = f
    }
    a.dataItems = {};
    var d;
    for (b = 0, e = a.dataItemNodes.length; b < e; b++) {
        d = a.dataItemNodes[b];
        a.dataItems[d.id] = d.content
    }
    for (b = 0, e = a.dataItemJsonNodes.length; b < e; b++) {
        d = a.dataItemJsonNodes[b];
        a.dataItems[d.id] = Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize(d.content)
    }
    var l = this._get_eventHandlerList().getHandler("pageLoading");
    if (l) l(this, this._getPageLoadingEventArgs(a));
    Sys._ScriptLoader.readLoadedScripts();
    Sys.Application.beginCreateComponents();
    var k = Sys._ScriptLoader.getInstance();
    this._queueScripts(k, a.scriptBlockNodes, true, false);
    this._processingRequest = true;
    k.loadScripts(0, Function.createDelegate(this, Function.createCallback(this._scriptIncludesLoadComplete, a)), Function.createDelegate(this, Function.createCallback(this._scriptIncludesLoadFailed, a)), null)
},
```

How should i modify the entire javascript or that function to add a custom delay feature?

So i can delay the client update at the client side as i wish after the postback is completed

Here my bounty having related question : [How to defer the update at the client side after async postback in updatepanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37237675/how-to-defer-the-update-at-the-client-side-after-async-postback-in-updatepanel)

Comment: @skyblade why do you remove that particular tag? it is exactly matching

Comment: No, it's not. AJAX Control Toolkit is just an assembly you use in your project by chance, but your question code and your problem has no affinity with that library.

Comment: @Skyblade i obtain these scripts from that assembly. Are you aware of that?

Comment: You obtain these scripts from the dependencies of that assembly. You can obtain it directly from [Microsoft.AspNet.ScriptManager.MSAjax](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.ScriptManager.MSAjax/) package.

Comment: @Skyblade ty for letting me know. I have even composed a sample project to test. Do you have any idea how can i solve my problem? https://github.com/FurkanGozukara/tempSite/

Comment: No, I just removed the question tag.